# Unable to activate publishing feature -> ContentQueryMain.xsl -> list does not exist

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2019, publishing, feature-activation, sharepoint-standard

When trying to activate the publishing feature on SharePoint 2019 I am only receiving an error message:

Fehler beim Instanziieren der Datei "ContentQueryMain.xsl" von Modul "XSLStyleSheets": Die angegebene Liste ist nicht vorhanden.

Tranlated:
Error instantiating ContentQueryMain.xsl file from XSLStyleSheets module: The specified list does not exist.

Unfortunately, I could not find anything about this issue online.

The issue seems to be related to my wss_content as I was able to enable the feature on the same server (single instance) on another web application I've created for testing purposes.

Appreciate any help as I am at a loss!

Comment: Has this site collection/content database been upgraded from a previous version of SharePoint?

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

It was the "Style Library".

1. Create a new SharePoint web application
2. Open SharePoint Designer and check in the root page the "Style Library"
3. When comparing I noticed that the Style Library from the broken site with the error message does have a different folder icon than the one from the working page and if I selected properties it behaved differently.
4. There is no function that simply re-creates that folder
5. Go to the working web application and export the style library as template (WITH contents!)
6. Import to broken SharePoint (_catalogs/lt/Forms/AllItems.aspx ?)
7. Delete the Style Library folder (or rename it)
8. Go to /_layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx and click "add an app" and select your imported template
9. Works - home that helps